# Connect to postgres from wildfly without password

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, wildfly, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-sql

I would like to run a `keycloak` (which is running in `wildfly`) in google kubernetes engine (GKE) and store my data in a managed SQL instance to which I would like to connect using a google service account (GSA) using the built in IAM authentication. I'm mostly through the setup (cloud SQL auth proxy is running as sidecar next to `keycloak`, the proxy successfully authenticates to the managed instance, etc...), but I cannot convince `wildfly` not to provide a password when trying to connect to the db via localhost (where the sidecar is available).

As an analogy to my problem I seem to have: `psql -U <service_account>@<project>.iam` works like a charm, where `psql -U <service_account>@<project>.iam -p` with empty password fails.

I already tweak the container which is using `jboss/keycloak` docker image by mounting my own version of `/opt/jboss/tools/cli/databases/postgres/change-database.cli` where I remove the line that sets the password. The file new looks like:

```
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS: remove()
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS: add(jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS,enabled=true,use-java-context=true,use-ccm=true, connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://${env.DB_ADDR:postgres}/${env.DB_DATABASE:keycloak}${env.JDBC_PARAMS:}, driver-name=postgresql)
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS: write-attribute(name=user-name, value=${env.DB_USER:keycloak})
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS: write-attribute(name=check-valid-connection-sql, value="SELECT 1")
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS: write-attribute(name=background-validation, value=true)
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS: write-attribute(name=background-validation-millis, value=60000)
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS: write-attribute(name=flush-strategy, value=IdleConnections)
/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=postgresql:add(driver-name=postgresql, driver-module-name=org.postgresql.jdbc, driver-xa-datasource-class-name=org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource)

/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=connectionsJpa/provider=default:write-attribute(name=properties.schema,value=${env.DB_SCHEMA:public})
```

(the standard content without the line: `/subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS: write-attribute(name=password, value=${env.DB_PASSWORD:password})`).

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you please provide more details about your environment and scenario? How did you configure your keycloak? It's custom configuration or configuration mentioned in [GCP Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/identity/keycloak-single-sign-on?hl=en)? Could you add more details about your SQL database? It's in `GKE cluster` or you've used `Cloud SQL/Spanner`? If I understand you are able to connect to your `GKE cluster` and `SQL instance` using `Keycloak` but you have an issue with `Wildfly`? Is your `Wildfly` deployed in the GKE cluster?

Comment: Setup:
- [GSA](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) is added (`cloudsql.instanceUser` and `cloudsql.client` is assigned)
- db is a PostgreSQL v11 running in `Cloud SQL` and above GSA as added as a SA user

- key for GSA is stored in a GKE secret

- keycloak is running as a deployment in GKE (image: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers), cloud SQL proxy is running as a sidecar next to keycloak.

keycloak is told to connect to the db on localhost (the sidecar make the proxy available there)

Comment: also, I debugged wildfly: it appears that `org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory#getConnectionProperties` sets an empty password in any case `props.setProperty("password", lcri.getPassword() == null ? "" : lcri.getPassword());`

Answer (score 2):

Typical. It was an error between the keyboard and the chair...

when created the db user I missed the `.iam` at the end (it looked like `<GSA_account_id>@<project_id>`, while it must be like `<GSA_account_id>@<project_id>.iam`

Comment: It happens :D I'm glad you were able to solve it. Please accept your answer, it won't give you any point but it will indicate that this was a solution for your issue.